# Create Python script that reads points(X,Y) from a fc, moves them in a user-defined distance and saves them in a NEW fc

Tags: arcpy, cursor, xy

i like to create a standalone Python script that reads points(X,Y) from a fc, moves them in a user-defined distance and saves them in a new fc. I tried to do the steps with the data access module, but i dont know so far how to go on, especially with the part "moving the XY-points" .

```
import arcpy 
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput= 1 
arcpy.env.workspace = "workspace"
outputFC = "New"
inFC = "inFC"

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("workspace","New","POINT")
cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("New", "SHAPE@XY")

point=arcpy.Point() 
cur2 =arcpy.da.SearchCursor("inFC",["SHAPE@XY"]) 
for row in cur2:
     print row
outputFC=row.GetValue("Shape")
point=outputFC.getPart() 
point.Y = pnt.Y
point.X = pnt.X  
array.add(point)  
feat.shape=array 
del row 
del cur 
del ins
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: These two questions probably answer most of what you need:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159206/moving-a-shapefile-point-500-m-west/159219 
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172003/how-to-move-a-feature-along-a-certain-angle-and-distance/172254#172254

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\FileGeodatabase.gdb'
projection = r'D:\SWEREF99TM.prj'

infc = 'inpoints'
outfc = 'outpoints'
#distance to move points
xoffset=1000
yoffset=2000

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path=arcpy.env.workspace, out_name=outfc, geometry_type='POINT', spatial_reference=projection)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc,["SHAPE@XY"]) as scur:
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outfc, ["SHAPE@XY"]) as icur:
        for row in scur:
            #create a list from the tuple SHAPE@XY which is retrieved by the search cursor
            xy=[element for tupl in row for element in tupl]
            #add xoffset and yoffset and create a tuple for use in the insertcursor
            xy2=((xy[0]+xoffset,)+(xy[1]+yoffset,),)
            #xy2 will for example be ((457591.43539999984, 6577837.267999999),)
            icur.insertRow(xy2)
```

[image]